# Permanently adding a new element to a SELECT box

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, select

I have a form with a SELECT box that is populated by a call to a mySQL database using php. This part is currently working so ignore the typos from creating this example.

```
<select name = "animal" id="animal" size="1">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from animals";
    $result = mysqli_query ($db, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">  <?= $row['animal'] ?> </option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

The id is the primary key of the option and is not shown (which is desired). If the current options are (bracketed numbers are the primary key of these elements, not shown to the user):

(1) Lions 
(2) Tigers

How can I make it so that the user could, for example, add Bears to the list, and have it appear on all future uses of this form? For bonus points, this particular element is repeated multiple times on the page, so it would be nice that if Bears is added to the first row, the second row will be updated to include Bears.

The actual table is very simple: id and animal, no other fields need to be filled.

Options on the table are php, javascript, jquery, and AJAX calls.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: You would just insert "Bears" in the database at the user's request.  You could print out the same `<select>` in multiple spots with a subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

So you would need a field for the missing animal, obviously.  Then once hit submit you could use ajax (jquery/javascript) to send it back to the server (php) which in turn would send back an updated list (json) that you could use to repopulate the given dropdowns using javascript/jquery.

Skills needed for this task would include php, mysql, ajax, json/xml and jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to recognise when this user comes back to your website, so give them a cookie, this may seem barely secure but think about it.

In that cookie either put the Bear's id, or some kind of key so that you could bring that id to bear when selecting their preference from your db.

If the id is an integer then is is quite trivial to filter it.

If you can see yourself changing ids in your db, then this would not work, but I cannot bear to think of anyone doing this.